# Syntax Highlighting in VIM after :bd

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

When I use`VIM`the syntax highlighting works, except after I return to a buffer using`:bd`the highlighting disappears. I can enable it again using`:syn on`.This problem occurs only for files without an extension. I remember I had to change some settings to get files without an extension to be highlighted in the first place, but I can't remember the details. (I use files without an extension because the`gf`command just works when I do this.) Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: In the end I used a workaround by mapping the `bd` command (and also `bp` and `bn`) to always enable syntax highlighting. This has the drawback of always highlighting the buffer, which you might not want. Here are the lines I added to my _.vimrc_ file:  `command BUFDEL :bd | syn on`  and  `cabbrev bd BUFDEL`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `:h modeline`   you should be able to set a comment in the file that tells vim what settings to use when you visit that file.

Comment: I didn't know about modeline, so thanks for that info. However, setting comments in the file isn't a good option for me, because they are shared with other people and there are thousands of files. Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to meta-data?

Comment: are you using the filetype plugin?  that make help

Comment: I've never heard of it, so I guess not. I use Vim on Cygwin most of the time - if that makes a difference? I've never knowingly used plug-ins in Vim before, but I'll check out filetype when I get some time.

Comment: try adding :filetype on  to your rc files (if it isn't already there).  It might help (it might not, all my files have extensions..)